# <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Warning: You should not use `Route component` and `Route children` in the same route; `Route component` will be ignored

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from "react";

import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import Playing from "./Playing";
import "./App.css";
import AllSong from "./Components/AllSong";
import Favourites from "./Components/Favourites";

function App() {

  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="box image photo">
      <SideBar sidebar={sidebar}/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Playing}>
            <Playing sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/AllSong" component={AllSong}/>
          <Route path="/Favourites" component={Favourites}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone explain why is the warning coming and also help to improve the code. (I'm new to react)
I tried using the v6 for react-router and react-router-dom b ut it showed number of errors so i degraded again and used `switch` again
Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have `<Route path="/" ...>` & within that you have `<Playing...` so this confuses the `Router` & it doesn't know whether to render the parent `<Route ...` or the child `<Playing...` hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

it is specifically these lines:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Playing}>
  <Playing sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}/>
</Route>
```

you're setting both the `component`

```
component={Playing}
```

and the `children`

```
<Playing sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}/>
```

React will only render one of them so one of them has to be ignored, in this case the component.

If you remove one of them the warning will disappear.

Comment: Can you help me with that ?

Comment: not sure I understand. Did it not work removing one of those code snippets?

Comment: None of them helped the code after being removed :(  it just gets blank and shows errors, both of them are important to the project

Answer (score 0):

Like the warning says, you can't specify both a route `component` ***and*** wrap children components.

From the docs:

> **Warning:** `<Route children>` takes precedence over both `<Route component>` and `<Route render>` so don’t use more than one in the
> same `<Route>`.

The issue is specifically with:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Playing}>
  <Playing sidebar={sidebar} setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}/>
</Route>
```

You are rendering `Playing` in both places. Since it seems like you want to pass additional props into `Playing` then I suggest using the `render` prop so `Playing` can also still receive [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), i.e. `history`, `location`, and `match` props.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  exact
  render={props => (
    <Playing
      {...props}
      sidebar={sidebar}
      setSidebar={(bool) => setSidebar(bool)}
    />
  )}
/>
```

See [Route render methods](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods) for further clarification on rendering routed content by a `Route` component.